# Plates have the pattern LLDDDD; that is, two letters then four digits. How many distinct registration plates are possible with this system?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I would think it would be $26\cdot26$ (for the two letters) and then for the digits it would be $10\cdot10\cdot10\cdot10$, so in total $26^2\cdot10^4=6760000$.

I don't know but I feel like im missing out on something.

Comment: Well, have you made any effort solving this yourself? What have you tried?

Comment: What are your ideas?
How many different letters can each space with $L$ have? How many different digits can each space with $D$ have? How can you combine these solutions?

A simpler example: You have a padlock with three digits $D_1 D_2 D_3$ and each of those can be 0 to 9. How many combinations are there?

Comment: sorry, see the updated post for what I have tried.

Comment: Your attempt with the answer of $26^2\cdot 10^4$ is exactly correct and is a routine application of the rule of product.  If it seems that the problem was too easy, that's because it really was that simple and straightforward.  You must learn to crawl before you can learn to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is perfectly fine - on a license plate with a pattern $LLDDDD$ you can choose 1 letter out of 26 twice $(26\cdot 26=26^2)$ and 1 digit out of 10 quadruple $(10\cdot 10\cdot 10\cdot 10=10^4)$. Then, by combining all possibilities you get $26^2\cdot10^4=6760000$ various combinations.